# Rectangle component with round corners

Tags: flutter, shapes, flame

I was googling for a solution on how to create a rectangle with round corners in Flame (Flutter), but didn't find any related examples or ideas.

Is there a way to do this?

I was trying to find a solution, but the only idea I have for now is to use SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant find anything related to rounded corner in docs .You can try extending shape component

https://docs.flame-engine.org/main/flame/components.html

```
class RoundedRectangleComponent extends ShapeComponent {
 RoundedRectangleComponent(double radius)
     : super(
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
         ),
       );
}
```

```
 add(RoundedRectangleComponent(30.0));
```